# Dynamic data update, no refresh or reload required

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

I have a form which lets the user enter some text and when the user submit the form.
that text gets returned and a image is generated by using PIL module of that text.

```
@app.route('/enter')
def index():
    img = Image.new('RGB',(1000,1000))
    txt=request.form['text']
    font=ImageFont.truetype("ariel.ttf",30)
    draw  =  ImageDraw.Draw ( img )
    draw.text ( ( 0 , 0), txt, font=font, fill="#000000" )
    io = StringIO()
    img.save(io, format='png')
    data = io.getvalue().encode('base64')
    return render_template('index.html',data=data)
```

this dynamic image is then forwarded to the webpage where it is shown

```
<img  src="data:image/png;base64,{{data}}" > // html shows the image
```

but this requires a reload or refresh of the page. Is it possible to use javascript or json to get the form data and render the image without refreshing the page.
Also i am using tabs to display the content of the page and this img which get dynamically updated as per the user response is contained in #tab4
How do i  set the url in flask:

```
@app.route('/enter#tab4', methods=[ 'POST'])
```

or simply

```
@app.route('/enter', methods=[ 'POST'])
```

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Exactly what bit are you having trouble with? This is a fairly simple bit of Ajax, and can be achieved pretty quickly with something like jQuery.

Comment: The main problem is showing the image. Every time the user click submit. It reloads the page and then i have to click on #tab4 manually to see the image that was generated. I don't want the page to refresh.

Comment: Sure, which is why you need Ajax. There is plenty of documentation on how to achieve this.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with Ajax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
      $('a#cal').bind('click', function() {
        $.getJSON('/t', {
          aa: $('input[name="text"]').val(),
        }, function(data) {
          $('#result').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data.result + '" />');
          });
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
```

and in the html:

```
 <form>
    <input type="text" size="5" name="text">
     <span id="result">
        </span>
        <a href="javascript:void();" id="cal">calculate server side</a>
    </form>
```

just make a function in your python code

```
@app.route('/t')
def pre():
    tx = request.args.get('aa', 0, type=str)
    //call function to perform some function on tx and then convert it to base64
    return jsonify(result=data)
```

This should serve your purpose. There will be no reloading or refresh required.